# A difference between Vdd and Vddio in datasheet of a sensor

Tags: power, sensor

In many datasheets of various sensors I read that there are two ways to supply power - that is VDD and VDDIO. I would like to know why we need to supply power in these two different ways.

Comment: You need to give an example data sheet where you see this.  Otherwise we are just guessing.  Guessing: Some sensors may need an analog power source free of digital noise or higher / lower than commonly used logic levels.

Comment: I guess, VDD would be a supply voltage for the sensor's core logic, whereas VDDIO is the voltage that IO can accept. To make it voltage universal, for example, the VDD can be 3.3V and the IO pins can support 2.8V, 3.3V or 5V input levels without the need of level shifters.

Comment: sir you can see the datasheet of HMC5883L or any other sensor

Answer (score 4):

> i wanted to know why we need to supply power through two different means

In your particular case, you can power your VDD with 2.16-3.6V see p.3 of the [HMC5883L](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/HMC5883L_3-Axis_Digital_Compass_IC.pdf) datasheet. Let's assume that your microcontroller works at 1.8V. That means, the logical signals from uC may be too low for the sensor. In this case, you would have to provide some voltage shifter/translator to increase your voltage to be in the required range of your sensor (2.16-3.6). Instead, the sensor manufacturer made universal logic to support lower levels of signals (in this case - down to 1.71V HI), so you do not need to worry about voltage compatibility between the chips. If all your chips use the same voltage, than your VDD and VDDIO can be connected to the same power supply.

Answer (score 2):

Sensors usually are so-called "mixed-signal" devices, meaning that they internally have some analog electronics (usually having higer quality supply), and some digital processing, or at least digital interface. One voltage rail (VDD in case of HMC5883L) is for ADC converter, and therefore likely requires cleaner power.

The VDDIO name speaks for itself, it defines voltage swing for I/O digital interface. In modern electronics with low-level signaling (which is better for faster speeds of communication links) the interface voltage is designed to be variable, for convenience of users, to use with low-level I/O signaling of modern microcontrollers.

Mixed-signal chips also usually have two grounds, AGND, and DGND. These grounds must be routed on PCB with some care, to avoid return current from digital "noise" flowing into more sensitive analog ground. The HMC5883L initially has mention the AGND and DGND (in voltage section), but the pin descriptions drop this distinction.

You can use one power supply and drive VDDIO equal to VDD, and use 3-V signaling for I2C, but I would put some LC de-coupling between the two rails anyway.